# Need Horizontal and vertical spacing in between controls

Tags: html

I am creating UI for angular application and using bootstrap 4. I need to apply horrizontal and vertical spacing in between controls. Could you tell me whats the best approach.
Currently all the controls are sticking to each other. I have created a stackblitz to replicate the issue.

[image]

Here is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uypvsy-hsbaav

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to inline classes from Bootstrap 4 on the individual elements, i.e. `mb-4` for margin bottom, `pr-2` for padding right 2 etc.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/

Comment: I am looking for some global styles that will apply across all form controls

Comment: You could just wrap the form in a class then select all inputs inside that? Wouldn't need anything from Bootstrap if you're doing that

`.form input {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}`